# copying one blob container data into another blob container in azure throught run books

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

i have write a script to copy one blob container data into another blob container
it copying only blob name and showing completed inside VHDs are not copying can any one please help in script,,,

what exactly i am trying is
ex:- storage account 1 contain 3 vhds
i have created new storage account in the same log and trying to copy all vhds into new storage account
In the script i have passed few parameters to copy the vhds with date
when i am running that script it only creating name but Vhds are not copying

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to copy all blobs to another storage accounts, we can use this script to do it:

Add this to a new runbook:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
$RGName = "vm"
$SAName = "jasondisk321"
$ConName = "vhd"
$key = "UUzQRoWeIMHzwzwJW9LxtgmwaJJS/Ac3DoXnPMHFIbUmupDpQ+KXCWG8ISJ4E20zjq7ugPtgN4vtVIv3A4m2Pg=="
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob * -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
$List = $List.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
$storageAccount = "jasondisk322"
$storageKey = "6lRJq6hTS1aHfVF4/iWskq/QS+tu4Jm/2zdz7Mo6AINGZOQKUiHtOAKmdZhBAWbcNEcBQq0YxZjXHgHha/iUKw=="
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext  –StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
$containerName = "vhd"
foreach ( $l in $list ){
$bn = ($l -split '/')[4]
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -srcUri $l -context $Ctx -DestContainer $containerName -DestBlob $bn -DestContext $destContext
}
```

If you want to use powershell on your local PC, we can use this script:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$RGName = "vm"  #source storage account resource group name
$SAName = "jasondisk321" #source storage account name
$ConName = "vhd"  #source container name
$key = "UUzQRoWeIMHzwzwJW9LxtgmwaJJS/Ac3DoXnPMHFIbUmupDpQ+KXCWG8ISJ4E20zjq7ugPtgN4vtVIv3A4m2Pg=="#source storage account key
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob * -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
$List = $List.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
$storageAccount = "jasondisk322"#destination storage account name
$storageKey = "6lRJq6hTS1aHfVF4/iWskq/QS+tu4Jm/2zdz7Mo6AINGZOQKUiHtOAKmdZhBAWbcNEcBQq0YxZjXHgHha/iUKw=="#destination storage account key
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext  –StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
$containerName = "vhd"#destination container name
foreach ( $l in $list ){
$bn = ($l -split '/')[4]
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -srcUri $l -context $Ctx -DestContainer $containerName -DestBlob $bn -DestContext $destContext
}
```

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with AzCopy:

```
AzCopy /source:https://[SourceStorageAccountName].blob.core.windows.net/vhds /dest:https://[DestStprageAccountName].blob.core.windows.net/vhds /sourcekey:<here-is-source-key> /destkey:<here-is-destination-key> /Pattern:[vhd-name].vhd
```

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy

If you want to automate, then you can use powershell using Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy:

```
Select-AzureSubscription "my subscription"  

### Source VHD (West US) - anonymous access container ###
$srcUri = "http://mwwestus1.blob.core.windows.net/source/testcopy1.vhd" 

### Target Storage Account (East US) ###
$storageAccount = "mweastus1"
$storageKey = "STORAGEACCOUNTKEY"

### Create the destination context for authenticating the copy
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext  –StorageAccountName $storageAccount `
                                        -StorageAccountKey $storageKey  

### Target Container Name
$containerName = "copiedvhds"

### Create the target container in storage
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $destContext 

### Start the Asynchronous Copy ###
$blob1 = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -srcUri $srcUri `
                                    -DestContainer $containerName `
                                    -DestBlob "testcopy1.vhd" `
                                    -DestContext $destContext
```

more info:https://www.opsgility.com/blog/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/copying-vhds-blobs-between-storage-accounts/

**UPDATE**:

AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/ /Dest:https://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/ /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:ab /SyncCopy

Comment: Thank you Thiago

i am trying to copy whole container not single VHds those all need to copy by parallel without  giving url of single vhds i am trying to give SourceRGName,& SourceSTGAccName & SourceCNTName & DestinationRGName & DestinationSTGAccName
is this possbile
can you please help me out in the script